# How to install angularjs correctly on an asp .net core project?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, bower

I tried to install the latest angularjs (1.5.5) via bower. It was taking already an hour so I tried installing an earlier version (1.5.0). It actually worked, but bower also tried to install 1.6.2. Now its taking forever for the build to finish. Is there something that I have missed along the installation?

[installation via bower installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqK5b.png)

Comment: You can forcefully install a specific version of angular using bower with this command. "bower install angular#1.5.0"

Comment: i tried also this one, but was unsuccessful on resolving the issue. For the meantime, i will try asp.net mvc. it seems that there is an issue on installing angular from bower.